# $db->res->prepare no longer working

Tags: php, mysql

Fighting some lines of codes, that I copied because I didn't know how to write the fields from an object to MySQL. This used to work, but after changing the fields, the program now never come in the "If true" section anymore. When using printf($stmt) or print_r($stmt) in the false section, it returns an empty string.

Any help appreciated.

```
    if ($stmt = $db->res->prepare("INSERT INTO rawdata( timestamp, NestName, NestUpdated, NestCurrentKelvin, " 
         . "NestTargetKelvin, NestTimeToTarget, NestHumidity, NestHeating, NestPostal_code, NestCountry, NestAutoAway, WeatherMain, "   
         . "WeatherDescription, WeatherTempKelvin, WeatherHumidity, WeatherTempMinKelvin, WeatherTempMaxKelvin, "
         . "WeatherPressure, WeatherWindspeed, WeatherCityName) "
         . "VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
 {
    printf("\nIf true");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssiiiisssiissiiiiiis', 
        $NestData['timestamp'],
        $NestData['NestName'],
        $NestData['NestUpdated' ],
        $NestData['NestCurrentKelvin'],
        $NestData['NestTargetKelvin'],
        $NestData['NestTimeToTarget'],
        $NestData['NestHumidity'],
        $NestData['NestHeating'],
        $NestData['NestPostal_code'],
        $NestData['NestCountry'],
        $NestData['NestAutoAway'],
        $NestData['NestManualAway'],
        $NestData['WeatherMain'],
        $NestData['WeatherDescription'],
        $NestData['WeatherTempKelvin'],
        $NestData['WeatherHumidity'],
        $NestData['WeatherTempMinKelvin'],
        $NestData['WeatherTempMinKelvin'],
        $NestData['WeatherPressure'],
        $NestData['WeatherWindspeed'],
        $NestData['WeatherCityName']
    );

    $stmt->execute();
    printf("\n%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
    if(mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt) > 0)
    {
        printf("Error Nr.\n", mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt));
        printf("Error  \n",mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
        $logRow = $logRow . "," . $stmt->affected_rows . "," . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $logRow = $logRow . "," . $stmt->affected_rows . ",No Errors\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
 }
 else
 {
     printf("\nIf false");
     print_r($stmt);
     printf($stmt);
     printf("\nEnd false");
 };
```

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: not sure why u use "." within your sql, but that could raise an issue, try to remove that

Comment: count your fields in your bind_param you have more then 22, but in your sql you have 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy these to lines into the bottom else statement, where you have your printf("\nIf false");

```
printf("Error Nr.\n", mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt));
printf("Error  \n",mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
```

This will tell you why the prepare fails. Then, based on that error, you can adapt. Likely an issue with column names in the database.

Comment: That shows nothing:
Connected to the database !!!

If falseError Nr.
Error

End false

Seems the $stmt isn't even filled at all with the first line. I will start rebuilding it in little steps.

Comment: Have rebuild the string from scratch and found a few little errors in the names used compared to the original string. Fixed now.